# Using strings in re expressions Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use a string in a regular expression expression. Example:

```
import re
def foo(text, pattern):
    pattern = re.compile(r'Get pattern some how', re.I)
    find = pattern.findall(text)
    ans = ' '.join(i for i in find).lower()
    return ans
text = input('Text:')
pattern = input('Pattern:')
foo(text, pattern)
ans = foo(text, pattern)
print(ans)
```

I am using python 3.6.4 and Mac OS X. What I need is that the pattern can vary according to the 'Pattern' string, then return it, and print it. Would I use string concatenation? Is there some other way? If you need any other information, just contact me via the comments. Thank you for considering the question!

Comment: what's your output of above code and what's expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the parameter `pattern` directly in the `re.compile()` where you would place the regex pattern.

```
import re
def foo(text, pattern):
    pat = re.compile(pattern, re.I)
    find = pat.findall(text)
    ans = ' '.join(find).lower()   # <--- `find` is a list already
    return ans
text = input('Text:')
pattern = input('Pattern:')
# foo(text, pattern)     <---- You don't need this line here
ans = foo(text, pattern)
print(ans)
```

Note I changed your local variable from `pattern` to `pat` to avoid confusion.  I removed the `list comprehension` as `findall` returns a `list` already. Also the first time you called `foo()` is rather pointless, since the returned result isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: Why did I not find this? No, a better statement is "Why did I not try this?"!